# Eclipse does not run Jboss standalone.conf

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss6.x

I'm using Eclipse Kepler integrated with Jboss EAP 6.3.

I need to set some system properties*, so I set them on JAVA_OPTS variable at the standalone.conf (jboss/bin).

* SSL configuration, like javax.net.ssl.keyStore.

It works fine when starting JBoss by command line (standalone.sh), but it does not work when starting JBoss by Eclipse. I checked that the system property was null, so I conclude that Eclipse does not run standalone.conf when starting JBoss.

Is this a Eclipse problem? Is there someway to fix this behavior? Or is there another way?

Tks a lot!

**Edition 1**

Eclipse configuration to launch JBoss:

Program arguments: `-mp "/home/myuser/apps/jboss-eap-6.3-sislv/modules" -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone-sislv-ws.xml`

VM arguments: `"-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss EAP 6.1 Runtime Server" -server -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/home/myuser/apps/jboss-eap-6.3-sislv/standalone/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/home/myuser/apps/jboss-eap-6.3-sislv/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" "-Djboss.home.dir=/home/myuser/apps/jboss-eap-6.3-sislv" -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true`

Comment: what your eclipse run configuration looks like?

Comment: Provided on "Edition 1"

Comment: the VM arguments are provided by eclipse, try to set them on the environment tab of the run configuration. If eclipse complains you cannot modify the run configuration you can manually edit the configuration in your workspace under `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your system properties as vmArgs in the Eclipse run configuration instead.

Comment: It is my current work around, but I don't like this way. Eclipse shouldn't modify too much the way we run JBoss. If JBoss reads standalone.conf when started by command line, why does it not do the same when started by Eclipse?

Comment: That's a good point. In your Eclipse run configuration, did you try having this: --server-config=/path/to/your/standalone.xml as one of the arguments to standalone.sh?

Comment: --server-config is already set by Eclipse configuration. But it's not an argument "of standalone.sh". Eclipse configuration to run JBoss seems to be not related to standalone.sh.

Answer (score 1):

Could be adding them as system properties in standalone.xml be an alternative solution?

```
 <system-properties>
    <property name="" value=""/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: No. The data we write on standalone.conf is workstation specific and it's not versioned. The standalone.xml is versioned, and therefore cannot contain workstation specific data.